# Localization in laravel

Tags: laravel, localization

I designed a site with Laravel. now I want add new language to it.I read [laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/localization) . It was good but I have a problem.suppose I have a page that show detail of products so I have a route like  mysite.com/product/id that get product's id and show it.also I have a method in controller like

```
public function showProduct($id){
  ...
}
```

If I add new Language , the route will change to this: mysite/en/product/id
now I must change my method because  now two parameter send my method.something like this :

```
public function showProduct($lang,$id){
  ...
}
```

So two problems arise:

1. I must change all method in my site which is time consuming
2. I do not need language parameter in methods because I set $locan via middleware 
   pay attention that I do not want remove for example en from my URL (because  of SEO)

Comment: maybe solve this problem by registering your supported languages routes explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your `RouteServiceProvider` and say that language parameter actually is not a parameter, it's a global prefix.

```
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'web',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        'prefix' => Request::segment(1) // but also you need a middleware about that for making controls..
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/web.php');
    });
}
```

here is sample language middleware, but it's need to be improve

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $langSegment = $request->segment(1);
    // no need for admin side right ?
    if ($langSegment === "admin")
        return $next($request);
    // if it's home page, get language but if it's not supported, then fallback locale gonna run
    if (is_null($langSegment)) {
        app()->setLocale($request->getPreferredLanguage((config("app.locales"))));
        return $next($request);
    }
    // if first segment is language parameter then go on
    if (strlen($langSegment) == 2)
        return $next($request);
    else
    // if it's not, then you may want to add locale language parameter or you may want to abort 404    
        return redirect(url(config("app.locale") . "/" . implode($request->segments())));

}
```

So in your controller, or in your routes. you don't have deal with language parameter

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'en'], function () {
    App::setLocale('en');
    //Same routes pointing to the same methods...
});
```

Or

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'en', 'middleware' => 'yourMiddleware'], function () {
    //Same routes pointing to the same methods...
});
```

Comment: thanks but I do not have problem with change my routes . after localization  , new parameter send my all function so I must change all of them that it is boring.I search for solution that new parameter(foe example : fa ) do not pass to methods

Comment: I think you would have to either do some changes in your routes, or do what you dont want to. See this very similiar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789577/is-it-possible-to-reorder-or-ignore-parameters-in-controller-routes